# Instantiating an object in array list

Tags: java, arraylist

An example of a method that uses a normal array object.

```
public static void free Customer(customer[] customers, supplement[] supplements)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<customers.length;i++)
        {
            customers[i]=new customer();
            customers[i].read Input();
            for(int s=0;s<supplements.length;s++)
            {
                supplements[i]=new supplement();
                supplements[i].read Input();
            }
        } 
    }
```

My question is, how do i convert this --> `customers[i]=new customer();` 
and this --> `customers[i].read Input();` into a valid Array list code?
I tried putting `customers[i]=new customer();` & `customers[i].read Input();`
into the method below but the compiler returns an error saying that 
"Array List required but array found"

This is a skeleton of the free Customer method that is using Array list.

```
public static void free Customer(Array List<customer> customers,
                                 Array List<supplement>supplements)
{
    for(int i=0;i<customers.size();i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with, the name of the class is `ArrayList`, not `Array List`.

Comment: There appear to be syntax errors in this class meaning it won't even compile. For example. Should "void free Customer" be "void freeCustomer". Should "customers[i].read Input();" be customers[i].readInput();

Comment: Assuming your method declaration is actually `public static void freeCustomer(ArrayList<customer> customers, ArrayList<supplement>supplements)`, then you need to know that an array (like `Customer[]`) and `ArrayList` are two totally different types so Java cannot simply implicitly cast from one to the other;  If you are being passed an array, you must keep the arguments as an array.   (ps, if it's your code, PLEASE keep to standard Java naming convention, which include class names start with an upper-case letter - `Customer` and `Supplement`, not `customer` and `supplement`)

Comment: Yes i know its not Array List but ArrayList. I put a space in between because stacks overflow wont accept the question when i wanted to post it. Dont worry, in my code in netbeans its written as ArrayList not Array List. I know that. This is clearly not answering my question tho. But its okay

Comment: I know that ArrayList and Arrays are 2 different things. My question is In a normal array if i wanted to instantiate everything in i would do something like this: customers[i] =new customer() ; how do i write something like this but for an arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public static void freeCustomer(ArrayList<customer> customers, ArrayList<supplement>supplements) {
    for(int i=0;i<customers.size();i++) {
        customers.set(i, new customer());
        customers.get(i).readInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ArvindKumarAvinash, when i run the code it did not execute the statement in the for loop you suggested. Upon checking it says that there is nothing in the customers.size() ArrayList. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means the customers list you are passing to the `freeCustomer` method is empty. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: how do i not make it empty? Do i declare something like this in the main method: custs.add(new customer()); Sorry. im new to using array list

Comment: Yes. If will add some customers to the list before passing it to the `freeCustomer` method, you will get its size>0 inside the `freeCustomer` method.

Comment: in the main method i got the array           
  ArrayList<customer> custs= new ArrayList<customer>();                                               Where do i add the customer. Below the statement or abover in the ()? I really appreciate your help. Right now what im doing is declaring the new customer and new supplement below the arraylist statement.

Comment: nevermind i give up with ArrayList

Comment: Wish you all the best!